# Confusion with an answer to a test question

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> While most scholarship on women’s employment in the United States
>   recognizes that the Second World War (1939–1945) dramatically changed
>   the role of women in the workforce, these studies also acknowledge
>   that few women remained in manufacturing jobs once men returned from
>   the war. But in agriculture, unlike other industries where women were
>   viewed as temporary workers, women’s employment did not end with the
>   war. Instead, the expansion of agriculture and a steady decrease in
>   the number of male farmworkers combined to cause the industry to hire
>   more women in the postwar years. Consequently, the 1950s saw a growing
>   number of women engaged in farm labor, even though rhetoric in the
>   popular media called for the return of women to domestic life.

Which of the following statements about women’s employment in the United
States during and after the Second World War is most clearly supported by the
passage?

1. Most women who joined the workforce during the Second World War
   wanted to return to domestic life when the war ended.
2. The great majority of women who joined the workforce during the Second
   World War were employed in manufacturing jobs.
3. The end of the Second World War was followed by a large-scale transfer of
   women workers from manufacturing to agriculture.
4. **The increase in women’s employment that accompanied the Second World War was longer lasting in agriculture than it was in
   manufacturing.**
5. The popular media were more forceful in calling for women to join the
   workforce during the Second World War than in calling for women to
   return to domestic life after the war.

**The given answer is (4), but to me (3) is also a probable answer because it states that numbers of female transferred to agriculture from manufacturing companies. 
Where am I wrong?**

Comment: When is your GRE? :)

Comment: @Tim , I thought more like TOEFEL :-)

Comment: on 30th September.

Answer (score 2):

(3) is never supported by the passage. Read clearly. The passage states, as a gist, the following points:

> (1) Women were hired during the war in manufacturing jobs.
>
> (2) The number of women working in the manufacturing jobs decreased when men started populating the industry after returning from the war.
>
> (3) In this industry, women were looked as "temporary workforce".
>
> (4) In agriculture, the requirement for women labor was constant before war and during war; the requirement in fact increased after a lot of male farmworkers did not return.
>
> (5) Consequently , in 1950 women labor increased in agriculture.

According to (3), women workforce was transferred from manufacturing to agriculture.

But if you observe carefully, the passage states that, women workforce was reduced in manufacturing industry but **never stated that those women who lost their job in manufacturing returned to agriculture**. The passage discusses about women workforce in agriculture separately with no relation to women working in the manufacturing industry.

(4) is absolutely correct. So, in a nutshell, **Requirement of women in manufacturing industry was not constant, it decreased after end of the war but those women did not return to agriculture (*at least not mentioned in the passage*), whereas requirement of women workforce in agriculture were constant during the war, rather it increased after the war.**

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is *transfer*, which means “move from one position to another”.

Although the passage implies that after the war fewer women were employed in manufacturing  and that more women were employed in agriculture, it does not say that they were the **same** women.

By and large, the women engaged in manufacturing are city-dwellers, while those engaged in agriculture are country-dwellers, so these business sectors drew their employees from different labor pools.

For the word *transfer* to be valid, you would have to suppose that large numbers of women moved from the cities to the countryside in order to secure employment. I suspect that that was not the case; and certainly this passage gives you no reason to suppose that it was the case.

I think what actually happened is that most city women who had been employed in manufacturing returned to their families, while in the country many women who had been employed outside the home on a supposedly temporary basis in fact remained on the job, while many more than before were employed outside the home for the first time.